# How to capture the event if a new process (application!) is started?

Tags: c#, process, pinvoke, unmanaged, hook

I would like to have some eventhandler which raise if a new application is started. I've heard that this is possible by using a hook but the only examples I can find are based on mouse/keyboard events.

What is an example link of how I can create such a hook in C#?

Oh and btw: Nope, I don't want to use [WMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation) which could be a solution as well but it's not an option in my case.

Comment: Why isn't WMI an option in your case?

Comment: I have sometimes used WMI for other applications and I had a lot of trouble with it, especially in case of remote WMI. Maybe this won't be due to the fact that the event-informations are local but I would like it to be the hooking mechanism. I have also read most of the times of the hooking way instead of using WMI. It sounds like hooking is more at the root of the information than WMI would be and therefore hooking would be more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a far from elegant solution which is perform a polling to the processes in the system.

```
Process[] currentProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();

List<Process> newlyAddedProcesses = new List<Process>();
while (true)
{
    newlyAddedProcesses.Clear();
    Process[] newProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process p in newProcessList)
    {
        if (!currentProcessList.Contains(p))
        {
            newlyAddedProcesses.Add(p);
        }
    }

    //TODO: do your work with newlyAddedProcesses

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    currentProcessList = newProcessList;
}
```

If your application doesn't need a high accuracy you can setup a big sleep time between polls which would make it much less time consuming.

Comment: This way I have to loop through all processes again and again and again. At the moment my application does work on a timer based way but I do not want to use a timer since there is a way to get to the real events. Timer based solutions are something like a waste of time and performance. But thanks anyway! :)